# How to use asyncio to continously read from a process and kill it after a timeout

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'd like to use asyncio to continuously read from a process until I stop it some time later. I've tried tons of things but can't figure out how to do it.

Here's one attempt that just doesn't seem to care about the `kill` at all

```
import io
import asyncio

class Foo():

    async def run(self):
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell('ping www.google.de', stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
        await asyncio.gather(self.run_proc(proc), self.kill_proc(proc))

    async def run_proc(self, proc):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            line = await proc.stdout.readline()
            print(line)

    async def kill_proc(self, proc):
        await asyncio.sleep(1000)
        print("meh")
        proc.kill()


f = Foo()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(f.run())
```

**UPDATE: Here's the working code incorporating the feedback from user4815162342**

```
import io
import asyncio

class Foo():

    async def run(self):
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('ping', 'www.google.de', stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
        await asyncio.gather(self.run_proc(proc), self.kill_proc(proc))

    async def run_proc(self, proc):
        while True:
            line = await proc.stdout.readline()

            if line == b'':
                break

            print(line)

    async def kill_proc(self, proc):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("meh")
        proc.kill()


f = Foo()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(f.run())
```

Comment: Is there really no better way to check if you've reached the end of stdout than `if line == b'':`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here's one attempt that just doesn't seem to care about the `kill` at all

Are you actually patient enough to wait for 16 minutes and 40 seconds for the `kill` to be called? If I change `await asyncio.sleep(1000)` to `await asyncio.sleep(2)`, the process does get killed in two seconds.

**EDIT** I've now tried it on a different system, and reproduced the issue. It turns out that `proc.kill()` kills the shell process (that waits for `ping` to finish), but not the `ping` process itself. A cross-platform workaround (that you've already [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404476/how-to-use-asyncio-to-continously-read-from-a-process-and-kill-it-after-a-timeou#comment89790917_51404816)) is to use `create_subprocess_exec`, which avoids the shell.

Additionally:

- when `ping` is killed, `run_proc` ends up in an infinite loop because the loop is missing something like `if line == b'': break`.
- you don't need to `await asyncio.sleep(0)`; the `readline()` is already a coroutine which will pass the control to the event loop while waiting.

Comment: Oops, seems I confused seconds with milliseconds there. However, it's weird because I do see the `meh` printed so I assume the `proc.kill()` is hit but it just keeps on printing pings (which do arrive in real time for me)

Comment: Ah, turns out that's caused by this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

It's working now. Thanks!

Comment: @Christoph Edited the answer to cover the new findings.